# TFS Build a project twice

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We have a solution with multiple projects. We'd like to build one particular project twice (running a script editing a few files from project in between these two builds) producing two different outputs.

Looking at the build template I can't navigate down to the level of individual projects, I can only see "build the solution" in the XAML. So I don't think we can perform any project specific actions there. Will I have to go down into MSBuild or are there other ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can.
From the "Items to Build" dialog, when you press the "Add" button, select "MSBuild Project files (*.*proj)" from the "Items of type" combo, then select your projects.
Beware that Default build template will go through the list of items to build and you cannot insert actions in between.

Comment: Excellent idea, nice and simple. Will have to edit the build template we're using but that was to be expected.